# Golang: how to determine a method is promoted from an embedded struct instead of being directly implemented

Tags: go, reflection

How can I tell if a method/interface is [promoted from an embedded struct](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types) (in other words: a struct "inherits" a method instead of directly implementing it)?

For example: is there a way to determine `Main` does not directly implement the interface `Interface` given this?:

```golang
type Interface interface {
  Method()
}

type Embedded struct{}
func (t *Embedded) Method() {}

type Main struct {
  Embedded
}
```

... as opposed to the case where it *does* directly implement the interface:

```golang
type Main struct {
  Embedded
}
func (t *Main) Method() {} // this is directly implemented
```

Tried:

Standard type assertion in `go` results in `Main` having the `Method` in both examples, implementing `Interface`, as expected:

```golang
main := &Main{}
_, implementsInterface := main.(Interface) // implementsInterface is true
```

Reflection also indicates an instance of `Main` has the method in both examples:

```golang
main := &Main{}

mainVal := reflect.ValueOf(main)
mainMethod, hasMainMethod := mainVal.Type().MethodByName("Method") // hasMainMethod is true

embedded := val.Elem().Field(0)
embeddedMethod, hasEmbeddedMethod := embedded.Type().MethodByName("Method") // hasEmbeddedMethod is true

// mainMethod != embeddedMethod
// pointers in the methods are not the same
// is there some other way to determine these methods are "the same"?
```

Comment: I'm curious: in what context does this distinction matter to you?

Comment: I would like to be able to recursively call an interface method optionally implemented by a struct and sub-structs. The embedded struct causes a problem that _both_ the top-level struct and the anonymous sub-struct implement the same interface method and it gets called twice. I would like to avoid calling this for the top-level structs that don't directly implement the interface method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will create a wrapper for a promoted method. So in the first place, the promoted method is different from the original method.

On the other hand, this fact gives us a not-so-reliable workaround: if a method is a wrapper, it could be a promoted method. And a still not-so-reliable way to check if a method is a compiler-generated wrapper is to check the file name of the source code corresponding to the method. For a wrapper, the file name will be `<autogenerated>`.

Let's see a demo first:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "runtime"
)

type inner struct{}

func (t *inner) Method() {}

type outer1 struct{ inner }

type outer2 struct{ inner }

func (o *outer2) Method() {}

func isPromoted(s any, methodName string) (bool, error) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    m, ok := v.Type().MethodByName(methodName)
    if !ok {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("method sets of s does not include the method")
    }

    p := m.Func.Pointer()
    f := runtime.FuncForPC(p)

    fileName, _ := f.FileLine(f.Entry())

    promoted := fileName == "<autogenerated>"
    return promoted, nil
}

func main() {
    i := &inner{}
    o1 := &outer1{inner: *i}
    o2 := &outer2{inner: *i}

    fmt.Println("i - is [Method] promoted?")
    fmt.Println(isPromoted(i, "Method"))

    fmt.Println("o1 - is [Method] promoted?")
    fmt.Println(isPromoted(o1, "Method"))

    fmt.Println("o2 - is [Method] promoted?")
    fmt.Println(isPromoted(o2, "Method"))
}
```

And the output (see https://go.dev/play/p/XUIE0ws3eFN):

```
i - is [Method] promoted?
false <nil>
o1 - is [Method] promoted?
true <nil>
o2 - is [Method] promoted?
false <nil>
```

This workaround is not-so-reliable because:

1. a wrapper is not necessary a promoted method. For example, when passing `i.Method` as a parameter to a function, a wrapper is created (follow the link above to the playground to see a demo). I'm not sure whether there are other cases.
2. the demo uses `(v Value).Pointer`. According to the [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Pointer):

   > If v's Kind is `Func`, the returned pointer is an underlying code pointer, but not necessarily enough to identify a single function uniquely.

   And the [comment in the implementation](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/91b8cc0dfaae12af1a89e2b7ad3da10728883ee1/src/reflect/value.go#L2165-L2170):

   > As the doc comment says, the returned pointer is an
   > underlying code pointer but not necessarily enough to
   > identify a single function uniquely. All method expressions
   > created via `reflect` have the same underlying code pointer,
   > so their Pointers are equal.

   Does `isPromoted` implemented in the demo work for methods created via `reflect`? It's not tested.
3. `<autogenerated>` is an implementation detail and is not documented. It could be changed any time.

Comment: For my use case, there is good news: structs created through reflect do not promote  embedded methods (there is an [issue in the golang tracker for this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15924)). And thank you so much for this, it's definitely the only way I've found to check this at all!

Comment: It works most of the time, but it do not work on android with one sample method `func (c *C) A() string{
 return c.R.URL.Path
}`. It works on mac, but not work on android. And I do not know why...